# Jackson JsonNode putPojo do not work for LocalDatetime

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am changing JSONObject to JsonNode in my project. It is easy to do with String or Primitive Type. However, when I attempt to put a pojo, especially the LocalDatetime property of it, it does not work.

```java
public class JacksonTest {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JacksonTest.class);
    final ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper()
            .disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
            .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());

    @Test
    void test() throws JsonProcessingException {
        User user = new User(1L, "Alice", LocalDateTime.now());
        log.info("user json is \n{}", om.writeValueAsString(user));
    }

    @Test
    void test2() throws JsonProcessingException {
        User user = new User(1L, "Alice", LocalDateTime.now());
        log.info("user json is \n{}", new ObjectMapper()
                .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule()).writeValueAsString(user));
    }

    @Test
    void test3() throws JsonProcessingException {
        User user = new User(1L, "Alice", LocalDateTime.now());
        log.info("user json is \n{}", new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(user));
    }

    @Test
    void test4() {
        User user = new User(1L, "Alice", LocalDateTime.now());
        log.info("user json is \n{}", om.createObjectNode()
                .putPOJO("user", user).toPrettyString());
    }
}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
class User {
    Long id;
    String username;
    LocalDateTime lastLogin;
}
```

I wrote a test class, but I got different results

1. test() and test2() return `{"id":1,"username":"Alice","lastLogin":"2023-11-28T09:25:06.7124585"}`, an expected result
2. test3() throws `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Java 8 date/time type 'java.time.LocalDateTime' not supported by default: add Module "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310" to enable handling (through reference chain: com.example.demo.test.User["lastLogin"])`, no surprise
3. test() return a json but contains an exception, that really confuse me

```json
{
  "user" : {
    "id" : 1,
    "username" : "Alice",
    "lastLogin" : "[ERROR: (com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException) Java 8 date/time type `java.time.LocalDateTime` not supported by default: add Module \"com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310\" to enable handling (through reference chain: com.example.winter.demo.User[\"lastLogin\"])]"
  }
}
```

The method *putPojo(String, Object)* does not seem to work consistently. In this case, I have to use the alternative method *ObjectMapper#valueToTree(Object)* instead.

Can anyone explain why this happens?

Comment: By the way, I cannot think of a situation where calling `LocalDateTime.now` would be appropriate. To capture a moment, use `Instant` or `ZonedDateTime`.

Answer (score 0):

In the `test3` you missed to register `JavaTimeModule()`:

```
@Test
public void test3() throws JsonProcessingException {
      User user = new User(1L, "Alice", LocalDateTime.now());
      log.info("user json is \n{}", new ObjectMapper()
                                   .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule())
                                   .writeValueAsString(user));
}
```

Issue `test4` Maybe the problem is about how the `putPOJO` method handles the LocalDateTime property in the `ObjectNode`.
The `putPOJO` method is used to add a POJO as a field in the ObjectNode, and in your case it encounters difficulties in serializing the `LocalDateTime` property.
To solve this problem, you can use the `valueToTree` method to convert the User object to a `JsonNode` and then add it to the `ObjectNode`:

```
@Test
public void test4() {
   User user = new User(1L, "Alice", LocalDateTime.now());

   ObjectNode objectNode = om.createObjectNode();
   objectNode.set("user", om.valueToTree(user));

   log.info("user json is \n{}", objectNode.toPrettyString());
}
```